# recommendation for gallery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, image-gallery, photo-gallery

i'm looking for a good/lightweight gallery script.
jquery, plain javascript or flash. any ideas?
it should be possible to display thumbnails and click for bigger view,
but also possibility to click through a series of images (previous/next button)

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flash based:

- [Monoslideshow](http://www.monoslideshow.com/)
- [Flabell Slideshow](http://www.flabell.com/flash/XML-Image-Slideshow-40)

Javascript + AJAX:

- [Building an Image Gallery with Progressive Enhancement](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/building-an-image-gallery-with-progressive-enhancement/)

[alt text http://nettuts.s3.cdn.plus.org/501_imagegallery/final.png](http://nettuts.s3.cdn.plus.org/501_imagegallery/final.png)

- [MinishowCase](http://minishowcase.net/)

[image]
<sub>(source: [smashingmagazine.com](http://media.smashingmagazine.com/cdn_smash/images/gal/minishowcase.jpg))</sub>

- [JonDesign's SmoothGallery](http://smoothgallery.jondesign.net/showcase/gallery/)

[image]
<sub>(source: [smashingmagazine.com](http://media.smashingmagazine.com/cdn_smash/images/gal/jondesignsSmoothGallery.jpg))</sub>

JQuery:

- [Simple Image Viewer](http://jqueryglobe.com/article/simple-image-viewer)

CSS-Based:

- [Cross Browser Gallery](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/lightbox.html#flower8)

Java Script+CSS+SWF Movies:

[SqueezeBox - Expandable Lightbox (v1.1)](http://digitarald.de/project/squeezebox/)

[image]
<sub>(source: [smashingmagazine.com](http://media.smashingmagazine.com/cdn_smash/images/gal/cross_browser_multi_page.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

FancyBox - http://fancybox.net/ is also good.

Answer (score 0):

Mootools is a very compact Javascript frameworks and here is also an ImageGallery script
based on Mootools

http://tutorialdog.com/javascript-image-gallery-using-mootools/

Answer (score 0):

I've put together a gallery which is simple all the way. Simple to use, simple to update.

See a demo here: http://nikc.org/galleries/index/

Comment if you're interested.